# Python Split data into multiple files with a rule

Tags: python, split

I need some idea to solve my problem in python to split a file.

I more than 1.000.000 rows in a file with 2 columns: "accountid" and a "property". One "accountid" can have multiple properties, but each property is one row. Looks something like this:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d2aVJ.png)

I need to split this data into 50.000 rows per file (which is not an issue). However, I one file also only allows 50 "properties" per "accountid". And a lot have more than 50 properties.

Do you have any **idea** how to technically solve this best? I do not require any code ;)

Thanks

Flo

Comment: So, if the item with accountid = 1 has 130,000 properties (i.e. shows up in 130,000 rows), you want it to 3 separate files (the first two files will contain 50,000 rows with accountid=1, while the 3rd file will have 30,000 remaining rows, along with 20,000 rows of other items)?

Comment: yes, but the splitting itself is not the issue. It gets complicated, because each file only is allowed to have 50 properties per one single id.

i have already a complex id to solve this. Like splitting first into like 40.000 batches and divided then running a second script which moves the ids with more than 50 properties to the other files.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution that comes to my mind:

First you have to determine how many partitions you will need, based on two parameters X and Y. X is determined by the accountid with the maximum number of properties. Let's assume accountid=7 has the maximum number of properties equal to 270 properties. That means you will need at least 6 partitions to ensure a solution exists where none of the partitions will have more than 50 of the acountid=7 rows (based on pigeonhole principle). Y is determined by the total number of rows you have and how big each partition is (in your example Y is 1000,000/50,000 = 20). We take the maximum of X and Y as the number of partitions we need. In this scenario: Number of Partitions = max(6, 20) = 20.

Now, you sort the entire table using accountid. Let's assume we know the row number for each row. We will then define Partition k as:

```
P_k = {row | row_number % 20 = k}
```

That should satisfy both of your requirements.

Note that if max(X, Y) = X, you will have to allow some partitions with less than 50K rows. Otherwise there is no solution to this problem.

Comment: thanks man! i already was thinking about this kind of approach but having this feedback from someone with a little more experience is great. i will try to incorporate this straight away. wish me luck ;)